# Why Apache IoTDB shows different timestamps reading data compared to settings when inserting data records?

Tags: timestamp, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to ask about the timestamp problem encountered in Apache IoTDB client. I try to execute insert_record using the current_unix_timestamp value, which is 1670249372 (corresponding to Mon Dec 05 2022 14:09:32 GMT+0000), but when IoTDB read the data, the timestamp was switched to 1970-01-20T07 :57:28.105Z, which is different from the original timestamp settings. I wonder if I did anything wrong on setting the original timestamp, any suggestions on the reason?

how to deal this question,someone help please

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this `current_unix_timestamp`value 1670249372 is a timestamp in seconds. Apache IoTDB uses milliseconds for timestamp by default. You can try to multiply this timestamp by 1000 when writing data and insert them again.